# weak star topology

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a compact Haussdorff space.
Someone can help me how to prove that $P(X)$ (the set of all Borel probability measures on $X$) is closed in the weak star topolgy?

Answer (score 0):

As part of the Riesz Representation Theorem Rudin (RCA)shows that a positive linear functional necessarily corresponds to a positive measure. [ The proof is somewhat lengthy]. If $\mu_n \to \mu$ weakly it follows that $f \to \int f d\mu$ is a positive linear functional  so $\mu$ is a positive measure. Of course $\mu(X)=\int 1d\mu=\lim \int 1d\mu_n=1$, so $\mu$ is a probability measure.